# CSS/HTML Weird text location in div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website at the moment, it has a fixed width on left column and a column on the right which fills the remaining width.
I have a problem where the text in the main column (The column on the left, where the main page content is going) seems to start half-way down the div which  is ugly, and not what I want. I would want the text in the main column start at the top rather than in the middle of the content box.

Online example of the site I'm working on http://creationation.eu/testsite/

```
#content{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 132px;
    margin-right: 455px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Not clear! plz specify which text is out of place? is twitter feeds column text? and what is your required output?

Comment: It's a whole new level of mess. You let almost everything `float` even those don't need to. It's really a miracle that browser can even render your page.

Comment: You must put your code to jsFiddle so people could easily play with it and provide you with the better and faster advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your css:

```
#content {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 3px none;
    float: left;
    height: 610px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    width: 535px;
}
```

and

```
#nav {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I realised that earlier, i am still very very new to web design, thanks for the help! :)